# Вопрос по поводу React Routing

Tags: reactjs, маршрутизация

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему не работает, когда я пытаюсь ввести **localhost:3000/services**
То выбивает **Cannot GET /services**
Страница Home прогружается, а вот **Services** не хочет . Но если я вместо **Home** поставлю **Services**, то страница **Services** загрузится

Answer (score 2):

Необходимо добавить в `Route` с `path="/"` props `exact`:

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
```

Подробнее об `exact` [тут](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Route/exact-bool)